# How to dock to the top and the left

Tags: c#, panel, anchor, docking

With An anchor I can write the following line:

```
myControl.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left);
```

And it will anchor `myControl` to the left and the top.

Why can't I do the following:

```
myControl.Dock = (DockStyle.Top | DockStyle.Left);
```

I can write the above line, but all it does is set the `DockStyle` to left.

Any thoughts/reasons for this?

Comment: i think you just didn't fully understand how to get the desired layout by using dock, anchor and some kind of container control (like TableLayoutPanel). With these elements you're able to built every kind of layout that will nicely scale with the size of your form/control. So if you provide more informations about what you like to achieve in your layout i'm sure we can find a solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason you cannot do this is because setting a `DockStyle` basically docks/fills the entirity of the specified edge.

For example, `DockStyle.Left` means that the height of the item being docked will always be the height of the container and the the X,Y location will always be 0, 0.

`DockStyle.Top` means that the width of the item will always be the width of the container and the location will always be 0,0.

Setting  `DockStyle.Top` and `DockStyle.Left` would essentially give you `DockStyle.Fill`. I.e. the same width **and** height as the container.

Comment: Thanks Gtt, that explains what I'm seeing.  I may have to pose another question about what I'm trying to achieve once I figure out how to phrase it!

Comment: No problem. I've been through all the pain of docking and anchoring myself, so I'll keep an eye out for the next question.

Answer (score 5):

A `Dock` is a pre-determined anchor set, whereas an `Anchor` is a custom dock configuration.

`DockStyle.Top` is the same as `Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right)` except that an anchor can sit at any initial position and a dock will move to the far edge.

Comment: They're kinda similar, but they're not the same. Anchoring allows you set locations away from the edges of the container. Docking forces the docked control to the specified edge. I.e. Left = 0. Top = 0.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea I did say this in my answer

Comment: So you did. My apologies, I apparently didn't read it properly.

Answer (score 2):

The `DockStyle` can only be set to one value, as opposed to the `Anchor` that can be set to many.

That is why there is the `Anchor` property so that you can adjust how the control reacts to the form resizing more specifically.

Comment: This is true, but what is the reason for this restriction on the docking and is there a way around it?

Comment: I don't know a specific reason why, I think the Dock is just for simple, easy docking of controls and wouldn't work having multiples (you couldnt have a dock style fill AND none for example) so thats why there is the Anchor as well.

Answer (score 0):

May be what you are looking for is the `Anchor` attribute:

```
myControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom  | AnchorStyles.Right
```